# Free solution for automated browser / mail / API testing

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, functional-testing

As the Product Owner of an application (with programming basics), which app would you recommend to put in place automated testing? I have several workflows to implement and they would rely on several services (my app, e-mails, data from API).

- Quotes funnel (with user account creation)
- Payment
- "My Account" tab
- E-mail check (Gmail)
- API check (data extract)

I see that Selenium is one of the preferred solution. But will it work to:

- check the content of an e-mail, out of Gmail for instance
- check the content of a simple DB query
- Put in place a "waiting time" of one day (between the payment and the moment where the product is updated by an external data source)

Comment: It is not that simple to answer this question but you can do it with selenium and other libraries.  For example you can use javaMail for checking the emails.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I will prefer [RobotFramework](http://robotframework.org/). With basic programming knowledge, we can automate different interface with predefined keyword libraries.

We can use

1. [Selenium library](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library) to interact web UI.
2. [HTTP library](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/#readme) to interact HTTP API.
3. [Database library](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) to interact Database.
4. [IMAP Library](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-imaplibrary/doc/ImapLibrary.html) to interact Mail

You just play with keywords available to test your application with different interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your context, a mixture of applications are going to be helpful.

- Yes you can use Selenium Web Driver for web application testing and Appium for native app testing. Since you have some programming experience you would be able to set it up and use it fairly quickly. You can do your UI tests and also talk to databases
- For API testing, you could use Selenium, if not you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) which makes testing APIs really easy
- To do an email check you would have to use third party email vendors like [Guerilla Mail](https://www.guerrillamail.com/) or [Mailinator](https://www.mailinator.com/) and then add code to send email to these vendors and do the necessary validations. They provide temporary email inboxes to help you do email validation.

There are also other open source/vendor tools out there to help you do this. So, you may want to invest some time in choosing the right platform for your automation needs.